# I want to find string sequence with rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to find string sequence with rxjs

for example

Target string: `01234010`

Match stringe: `01`

answer = 2

I have a solution with using javascript

```
let index = 0;
while (true) {
  let foundIndex = targetSequence.indexOf(matchSequence, index);
  if (foundIndex == -1) break;

  index = foundIndex + 1;
}
```

but the problem is that I have to use rxjs with those skeleton code

```
import { from, Observable } from "rxjs";
const targetSequence = `01234010`;
const matchSequence = "01";

const _target = from(targetSequence);
const _output: Observable<number> = _target.pipe(
  // here is your code
);

_output.subscribe({
    next: val => console.log(`count : ${val}`)
  });
```

do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you could use the rxJS operator `map`.

E.g.

```js
const targetSequence = '01234010';
const matchSequence = '01';

const _target = of(targetSequence);
const _output = _target.pipe(
  map((val) => {
    let foundIndex = val.indexOf(matchSequence);
    return foundIndex + matchSequence.length;
  })
);

_output.subscribe({next: (val) => console.log(val)})
```

*Note:* I've used the `of` method to generate the observable, using `from` emitted for each character. I've also slightly modified your method of finding the result but I think it achieves what you want.

Comment: is there a way I can solve this problem with using `from' not 'of' you edited?

Comment: There is, but it's not ideal, you'd need to add an additional operator within the pipe to combine the emissions back into a string.

So adding `reduce((acc, val) => acc + val)` before the map works when using `from`.

Comment: hey Rob, I thought your answer is correct but what I wanted is to count how many match sequence appears in target sequence :) lol... T_T but I appreciate your answer